# Telling whether before or after latest save

Tags: undo-redo

Sometimes I get lost undo/redoing (sometimes having accidentally applied a count). I can't tell if I'm before or after the latest save and spam u/U until I see the [+] indicator next to the filename disappear.

Is there a way to tell where I am relative to the latest to save?

Answer (score 2):

I personally used the [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) plugin for that.

[image]

Your current position in the undo three is marked with `>nnn<`.

The last saved position is marked with `S` (in blue in the screen shot the other S with yellow background correspond to older saved version)

That being said you could be interested by the following command:

```
:earlier 1f
```

If you are ahead of the last saved state, it undoes the changes of the current undo branch to bring back your buffer in a saved state (without modifying the undotree like `:e %` would do).

If you still in the undo branch of the last saved state it is equivalent to hit `u` until the `[+]` is gone.

If you have left the undo branch of the last saved state you have to use undotree or use the `g-` step wise until the `[+]` is gone (since `u` and <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> stay in the current undo branch).

If you are behind the last change you have to use `:later 1f`